# Get value from website textfield using powershell

Tags: powershell, jira, webrequest, ps

Im trying to make a powershell script that retrieves a value from our Jira website using Invoke-WebRequest.
So far i tried this, without success:

```
$URI = "https://jira-marine.johnsoncontrols.com/browse/MST-3846"
#$URI = "https://superwidgets.wordpress.com/category/sql/"
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI
#$HTML.ParsedHtml | Get-Member
$HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementById('customfield_23231-val').value 
#$HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('('customfield_23231')
($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('input') | Where{ $_.className -eq 'customfield_23231'}).innerText
#($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('h2') | Where{ $_.className -eq 'entry-title'}).innerText
```

I've included a screenshot from the websites DOM, how do I get that value (664597)?
Is it a issue with access to the page, as it require login?

[DOM from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT0Wp.png)

Comment: Try using HtmlAgilityPack: https://html-agility-pack.net/  it has been really helpful for me.  See this article for how to authenticate on a website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298532/htmlagilitypack-and-authentication

Comment: You *might* be better off using the JIRA API if that's an option - see https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/ - that way you won't have to parse html at all...